# why my alarm manager working at the wrong time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am new to coding and android studio. and now I'm trying to build a calorie counter on android. I try to push data every 12 in the morning (11:59 PM), but what happens is that every time I force to close the application after 11:59 and return to the application (activity) the data will be pushed again.there are many tutorials that I see on youtube, stackoverflow and github. but I haven't found an active one automatically (onCreate ()), so I need to ask here. This is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_status_body);

        //some code
        //some code

        Calendar calendarGo = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarGo.set(
                calendarGo.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendarGo.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendarGo.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                23,  59, 59);
        setAlarm(calendarGo.getTimeInMillis());

        // some code
        // some code

        }

        private void setAlarm(long time){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BroadCastReceiverTester.class);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, mainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1321, intent, 0);


        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }
```

**BroadCastReceiverTester.java**

```
 public class BroadCastReceiverTester extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     // some code
     // some code 

 activity activity = new activity(activity_id, activity_name, 
 activity_minutes_perfomed, activity_calories_burned,
 activity_date);

 databaseReferenceActivity.child(activity_id).setValue(activity);    
 }
```

What I want to say is, I want BroadCastReceiver to function only at the time I set (ie 23:59:59), but the reality always works every time onCreate is launched.
Thank you

Comment: From docs: "Beginning with API 19 (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent)." As you can see, there are a lot of reason how this can go wrong. It's better to use WorkManger for this things: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Answer (score 0):

If you want every day at 12:00 what you need to do is set the alarm like this:
`Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);` .

then set the alarm like this:

```
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: when I change the code that I made with the code that you made, the data does not enter the database. I managed to get the data into the database right at 12 in the midnight . but the problem is when I apply the OnDestroy (force close) and then re-open it (which means it is not 12 midnight) it will re-enter the data into the database.